# mongoid return object contains references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

so i'm using Mongoid and i want to return an object with it's refference. lets say i have:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :pictures
end

class Picture
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
end
```

the problem is with this code:

```
users = User.all #goes to the db
users.each do |user|
  pic = user.pictures.first # <--- bad! hitting the db again here
end
```

so, how can return an object (user) that contains it's refference so i wont need to hit the db again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would normally be done with joining in ActiveRecord. Something like this:

```
 User.includes(:pictures).each do |user|
```

But since MongoDB doesn't support joins, there's no way to load parent document and its referenced documents in one go. If this becomes a problem, you should consider embedding pictures in a user document (this, however, may cause more serious performance penalties).

#### Update

Mongoid has a way to [eagerly load](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) (search the page for "Eager Loading") referenced relations, but still separate queries are made. Database won't be hit on subsequent access of a relation.